# Tkinter event's widget attribute is not a widget

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-entry

I'm trying to make all `tkinter` `Entry` objects map Control-C to a copy event (and similar defaults for other commonly used shortcuts).  This works for most `Entry` objects, but fails in a strange way for a file dialog.  A minimal example is below.  I'm using Python 3.8.6 with Tkinter version 8.6.

```
import tkinter
from tkinter import filedialog
from tkinter import ttk

def ctrl_c_callback(event):
    # I would like to do something like:
    #   event.widget.event_generate("<<Copy>>")
    # but this results in the error
    #   AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'event_generate'
    # due to the fact 'event.widget' is a 'str' rather than a widget,
    # as will now be demonstrated.
    print(event.widget.__class__)

root = tkinter.Tk()
root.bind_class("TEntry", "<Control-c>", ctrl_c_callback)
save_button = ttk.Button(root, text="Save", command=filedialog.asksaveasfile)
save_button.grid()
root.deiconify()
root.mainloop()
```

Running this and clicking "Save" produces a dialog box, as expected.  Now I select some text in the "File name" field near the bottom...

[image]

...and hit Control-C.  I get:

```
<class 'str'>
```

I find this extremely surprising.  Shouldn't `event.widget` be a widget?  Specifically, shouldn't it be an `Entry`?  Clearly, the event was triggered by an `Entry`, because otherwise the Control-C binding should not have done anything.

If this is relevant, the value of the string is

```
.__tk_filedialog.contents.f2.ent
```

which seems like it might be the name of a widget in Tcl.  (I do not know much about Tk in general.)  As a last-ditch attempt, I tried using the `root.nametowidget` method on this to see if I could get a widget, but this resulted in a `KeyError`.

Note that, for other `Entry` objects that I have manually created, I have no trouble getting the Control-C callback to copy the text as desired.

Comment: when I skip `bind_class` then I can stil use `Control+C` to copy text from `Entry` in `filedialog` - so this object already have binded this combination. And maybe this makes problem.

Comment: It seems it uses `ttk.Entry` instead of `tkinter.Entry` and it behave in different way.

Comment: @furas I think that this depends on the system defaults.  But I can reproduce the problem by binding to something else, like Control-A, as well.

Comment: Oh, interesting.  How can you tell whether it is using `ttk.Entry` or `tkinter.Entry`?

Comment: I'm not sure if they use `ttk.Entry` but I created both in main window and I see they look different - at least on Linux - `ttk.Entry` has white background like in `filedialog` but `tkinter.Entry` has gray background. But now I used `print( filedialog.__file__ )` to get path to source code and check it.

Comment: `root.nametowidget()` would have been the proper solution - except that it only works on widgets explicitly created by your code.  You're going to need to do this directly in Tcl - try `root.tk.call("event", "generate", event.widget, "<<Copy>>")`.

Comment: @jasonharper Works beautifully.  So then is my understanding basically correct, that the string is actually the name of a `Tk` widget that I don't have access to in Python?  If you post as an answer then I will accept it.

Comment: The underlying Tk implementation just uses widget names everywhere - they aren't first-class objects like the Python wrapper makes them appear to be.  `event.widget` is the only place I can think of where this is actually visible in Python.

Comment: @jasonharper I agree with @sasquires you should send it as answer. I found it runs `Tk` widget `tk_getSaveFile` I got the same problem with `root.nametowidget()` to access it as widget.